# Wikidata Syntax for Querying commanders of kz dachau

Tags: sparql, wikidata

i am new to wikidata and i have tried to query query the start/ end dates of the commander of the kz dachau using sparql. I have following code but i don't get any data.

```
SELECT ?KZ_Dachau ?start ?end ?name
WHERE
  {?KZ_Dachau p:P1037 ?leiter.
  ?leiter ps:P1037 wd:Q151198;
          pq:P580 ?start;
          pq:P582 ?end.
   ?KZ_Dachau wdt:P1559 ?name. }
```

a similar query, on which my query based, works fine:

```
SELECT ?papst ?start ?end ?name ?pic
WHERE 
{?papst p:P39 ?position.
?position ps:P39 wd:Q19546;
pq:P580 ?start;
pq:P582 ?end.
?papst wdt:P1559 ?name.}
```

what i doing wrong?

I think my approach is wrong, but i don't know how to resolve it :/ And i dont understand, why i can't select any properties of the entity kz dachau (Q151198).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you got the order wrong, i.e. in WikiData, the property director/manager has a person as **object**, not subject as in your query.

This query will work:

```
SELECT ?KZ_Dachau ?start ?end ?name
WHERE
  {wd:Q151198 p:P1037 ?leiter. #Notice the change in order
  ?leiter ps:P1037 ?KZ_Dachau;
          pq:P580 ?start;
          pq:P582 ?end.
   ?KZ_Dachau wdt:P1559 ?name. }
```

Also, you may use property paths, in this case `^` inverts the property, so that `?a :hasChild ?b` will be exactly the same as `?b ^:hasChild ?a`:

```
SELECT ?KZ_Dachau ?start ?end ?name
WHERE
  {?KZ_Dachau ^ps:P1037 ?leiter.
  ?leiter ^p:P1037 wd:Q151198;
          pq:P580 ?start;
          pq:P582 ?end.
   ?KZ_Dachau wdt:P1559 ?name. }
```

P39 in WikiData on the other hand has a person as a subject, hence why that query works. However, if you look at [Eicke](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q65098), WikiData just says that he held the position of member of the Reichstag, and says nothing about him being manager/director at Dachau.